# How to swap the values of 2 parameters in method Java

Tags: java, swap

i want to swap the values of 'a' and 'b' and to return their values. I tried void type but it didnt swap the values. Now im trying this but eclipse saying that i didnt use 'return'.

```
public class swap {
    public static int swap(int a, int b) {
        int temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
        int[] array = { a, b };

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            return array[i];
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(swap(10, 5));

    }

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Learn some basic Java please.

Comment: im trying to swap the value of 'a' and 'b', So if i write 10 and 5 to print 5,10

Comment: `public static int[] swap(int a, int b) { return new int[] {b,a}; }` but you'll need to print it as an array (not an `int`).

Comment: how exactly to print it

Comment: `int[] swapArray = swap(10, 5);
     System.out.print(swapArray[0] + "," + swapArray[1]);`